# ClientDataSet Data can't be updated to the server or even posted

Tags: sql-server, delphi

So , i'm creating a datasnap TCP/IP server multiitier data base in Delphi XE7, i used in the server a mssql Database then connected it used a datasetprovider

in the Client Side i made a sqlConnection for connecting to DataSnap Server then i used a dsproviderconnection then i used "ClientDataSet"

when i run the Client Application i will a serval rows and post the modifcation but if i desactivate the ClientDataSet then reactivate it the data will be lost

so help me please i cant see what is the probleme there no error or something like that?

and thank you

Comment: excuse me for the english

Comment: The English is not the problem. You need to show some code. And if you're getting error messages, you need to state exactly what error you're getting. [Edit] your question and add a [mcve]. But be aware that simply "positng modifications" is not enough to retain data in a client data set. That data is in memory only until you `ApplyUpdates` or do something else to persist it.

Answer (score 0):

Either don't deactivate the ClientDataSet (the data will get lost as you found) or save the data to a file or stream and reload it afterwards (SaveToFile/Stream, LoadFromFile/Stream).

Comment: Please provide a minimal example showing your problem. Describe what you do, what you expect and what is happening instead.

Comment: Also, provide the error message that your ApplyUpdates raises.

Comment: click on the clientdataset and in the object inspector go to events and doublclick on OnReconcileError and write something simple like   ShowMessage(e.Message); Then tell us what the errormessage is after ApplyUpdates();